# How do I display the circles in the center in my program

Tags: python, loops, pygame, geometry

So basically this program works almost correctly, it should display a simulation of concentric circles, the only big problem, is that I don'y know how to display the circles in the center, since in the middle there only is an empty space

I have tried by using the same concept as by the rest of the circles, and changed only the range, so that it stays in the middle, but it did not work as I wanted. So I just let the program display a circle in the middle that should have a radius that fits for all the frequencies

```
import pygame
import math
import time


pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Kreise")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,700])

width_2 = int(screen.get_width() / 2)
width_3 = int(screen.get_width() / 3)
height_center = int(screen.get_height() / 2 )



black = (0,0,0)
keep_going = True
onecircle = False
twocircles = False
threecircles = False
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
freq = 0
circle1spot = (0,0)
circle2spot = (0,0)
circle3spot = (0,0)
freq2 = 0
freq3 = 0
pointradius = 3
num_circles = 0
num_circles2 = 0
num_circles3 = 0
radius = 0
radius2 = 0
radius3 = 0
centerradius = 14
howmanycircles = int(input("How may circles, MIN [1], MAX [3], DEFAULT [1] \n"))




if howmanycircles == 1:
    onecircle = True        
    freqinput = int(input("Frequency first circle, MIN [1], MAX [148]: \n"))
    if freqinput > 148 or freqinput == 0:
        print("Answer not correct, 120 selected as default")
        freqinput = 120
    freq = 150 - freqinput


elif howmanycircles == 2:
    twocircles = True

    freqinput = int(input("Frequency first circle, MIN [1], MAX [148], DEFAULT [120]: \n"))
    if freqinput > 148 or freqinput == 0:
        print("Answer not correct, 120 selected as default")
        freqinput = 120
    freq = 150 - freqinput

    freqinput2 = int(input("Frequency second circle, MIN [1], MAX [148], DEFAULT [120]: \n"))
    if freqinput2 > 148 or freqinput2 == 0:
        print("Answer not correct, 120 selected as default")
        freqinput2 = 120
    freq2 = 150 - freqinput2


elif howmanycircles == 3:
    threecircles = True
    freqinput = int(input("Frequency first circle, MIN [1], MAX [148], DEFAULT [120]: \n"))
    if freqinput > 148 or freqinput == 0:
        print("Answer not correct, 120 selected as default")
        freqinput = 120
    freq = 150 - freqinput

    freqinput2 = int(input("Frequency second circle, MIN [1], MAX [148], DEFAULT [120]: \n"))
    if freqinput2 > 148 or freqinput2 == 0:
        print("Answer not correct, 120 selected as default")
        freqinput2 = 120
    freq2 = 150 - freqinput2

    freqinput3 = int(input("Frequency third circle, MIN [1], MAX [148], DEFAULT [120]: \n"))
    if freqinput3 > 148 or freqinput3 == 0:
        print("Answer not correct, 120 selected as default")
        freqinput3 = 120
    freq3 = 150 - freqinput3

else:
    print("Answer not correct, 120 selected as default")
    onecircle = True
    freqinput = int(input("Frequency first circle, MIN [1], MAX [148], DEFAULT [120]: \n"))
    if freqinput > 148 or freqinput < 0:
        print("Answer not correct, 120 selected as default")
        freqinput = 120
    freq = 150 - freqinput


def circle1(radius, centerradius):
        radius = radius + 1
        num_circles = math.ceil(radius / freq)
    #screen.fill(white)

        radiusMax = num_circles * freq

        pace = freq / radiusMax

        #centerradius = int(((pace * (num_circles - 2)) + pace) * radiusMax)# + (radius % freq)



        for y in range(num_circles, 1, -1):


        # 1, -1

            radiusY = int(((pace * (num_circles - y)) + pace) * radiusMax) + (radius % freq)




            pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, circle1spot, centerradius, 1 )
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, circle1spot, radiusY, 1)



    #pygame.display.update() 
        return radius

def circle2(radius2, centerradius):
        radius2 = radius2 + 1
        num_circles2 = math.ceil(radius2 / freq2)
    #screen.fill(white)

        radiusMax = num_circles2 * freq2

        pace = freq2 / radiusMax


        for y in range(num_circles2, 1, -1):
        # 1, -1

            radiusY = int(((pace * (num_circles2 - y)) + pace) * radiusMax) + (radius2 % freq2)





            pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, circle2spot, centerradius, 1 )
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, circle2spot, radiusY, 1)

    #pygame.display.update() 
        return radius2

def circle3(radius3, centerradius):
        radius3 = radius3 + 1
        num_circles3 = math.ceil(radius3 / freq3)

        radiusMax = num_circles3 * freq3

        pace = freq3 / radiusMax


        for y in range(num_circles3, 1, -1):

            radiusY = int(((pace * (num_circles3 - y)) + pace) * radiusMax) + (radius3 % freq3)


            pygame.draw.circle(screen, green, circle3spot, centerradius, 1 )
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, green, circle3spot, radiusY, 1)

        return radius3












while keep_going:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            keep_going = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            #mousedownleft = True
                circle1spot = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                print(circle1spot)



            elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:
            #mousedownright = True
                circle2spot = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                circle3spot = pygame.mouse.get_pos()




    pygame.draw.circle(screen, blue, (width_3,height_center), pointradius, 3 )
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, blue, ((width_3*2),height_center), pointradius, 3 )  
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, blue, ((width_2),height_center), pointradius, 3 )    
#pygame.display.update()

    if onecircle == True:
        radius = circle1(radius,centerradius)
    #pygame.display.update()

    elif twocircles == True:
        radius = circle1(radius,centerradius)
        radius2 = circle2(radius2, centerradius)

    elif threecircles == True:
        radius = circle1(radius,centerradius)
        radius2 = circle2(radius2, centerradius)
        radius3 = circle3(radius3, centerradius)



    #clock.tick(500)



    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill(white)

    #pygame.time.wait(100)
    #pygame.time.delay(10)

    #time.sleep(.005)
    #screen.fill(white)
    #pygame.display.update() 




pygame.quit()
```

I'm looking for an algorithm to display the circles in the middle, or a different possible solution

Comment: centerradius "14" is the common radius for all the circles drawn in the middle

Comment: Ok, so what doesn't work? A circle with the `centerradius ` is drawn in the center of the 3 animations. What is wrong?

Comment: if you run the code you will notice that if you set a high or low frequency, you will see that the circle drawn with centerradius does not exactly start where the first circle of the animation starts, this is due to the fact that 14 is only an approximative radius that should fit for all, but it is not exactly correct.https://www.edumedia-sciences.com/de/media/645-kreiswellen-wasserwellen this should give you an idea of what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum radius of a circle is `int(pace * radiusMax)`.

Draw a "center" circle with this radius:

e.g.

```py
centerradius1 = int(pace * radiusMax)    
pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, circle1spot, centerradius1, 1)
```

---

If you would pass the paramters like center point, frequence and the color of the animation to a function circle, then you would be able to use one function `circle` for all the animations:

```py
def circle(radius, center, freq, color):
    radius = radius + 1
    num_circles = math.ceil(radius / freq)
    radiusMax = num_circles * freq
    pace = freq / radiusMax

    centerradius = int(pace * radiusMax)    
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, center, centerradius, 1 )

    for y in range(num_circles, 1, -1):
        radiusY = int(((pace * (num_circles - y)) + pace) * radiusMax) + (radius % freq)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, center, radiusY, 1)
    return radius
```

Call the function `circle` like this:

```py
while keep_going:

    # [...]

    radius = circle(radius, circle1spot, freq, black)

    if twocircles == True or threecircles == True:
        radius2 = circle(radius2, circle2spot, freq2, red)

    if threecircles == True:
        radius3 = circle(radius3, circle3spot, freq3, green)
```

Comment: @MILO.PY Thank you. You're welcome. You can simplify your code, see the extension to the answer, which I've add right now.